# How store incoming data from serial port in bash?

Tags: bash, scripts, serial-port, modem

I try a little bash script for a analog serial modem to record  an incoming call.
The commands for voice mode, compression and silent dedtection will return OK. So I am ready to receive data. For these commands I use socat.
the point is now how can I store incoming data after the AT+VRX command.
I think that socat could be a solution  but have no idea of the correct syntax.

have someone an idea how I can receive and store incoming data?

Comment: `bash` is not the right tool for dealing with modems. Asynchronous devices (like modems) are better handled with `expect`. Read `man expect`.

Comment: @waltinator  Hi,   
I feel myself overchallenged by the man of expect.   
But I think that you are familiar with this and so I would be very  pleased if you would write me how to use the expect command for my little application.

Comment: Reading "man pages" and figuring out what they mean is a neccessary Linux skill. AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. Type "linux expect examples" into an internet search engine.